# Is there an equivalent of MAKECMDGOALS in bazel?

Tags: bazel

In GNU make, the `MAKECMDGOALS` variable contains all the targets specified on the command line. Is there an equivalent in bazel? If I run

```
$ bazel build //:larry //:curly //:moe
```

can I get a list containing

```
[ "//:larry", "//:curly", "//:moe", ]
```

?

Comment: Maybe you looking for `bazel query //...`?

Comment: No, I'm not looking for `bazel query`. I want to use `bazel build`, but some targets are mutually exclusive because reasons, and I would like to check that only compatible targets have been specified.

Answer (score 1):

While various logging facilities such as the [Build Event Stream](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/build-event-protocol.html) receive Bazel's command line, there is no way to read the list of targets to be built from a `BUILD` or `.bzl` file. With the exception of [exclusive tests](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/test-encyclopedia.html#tag-conventions), Bazel does not allow for graceful handling of mutually-incompatible build steps.